# Assign values to points according to a pattern

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression

I'm making a map of trees in QGIS (3.10). Each point represents a tree and the attribute table has a column that should contain the tree species. For now this column is empty, but I would like to fill this column. The trees are planted in a pattern, for example cashew tree - baobab tree - banana tree.

How can I assign the tree species to the table according to the pattern? So every first tree is a cashew, every second tree is a baobab and every 3rd tree is a banana. The fid of the table is in the right order, so I could build an expression with fid+0 = cashew, fid+1 = baobab and fid+2 is banana. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the field calculator, select the function editor and make the content look like:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def tree(value1, feature, parent):
   trees=['Cashew','Baobab','Banana']
   idx=value1%(len(trees)-1)
   return(trees[idx])
```

Press "Save and load functions" then in the Expression tab, type

```
tree(fid)
```

If you want the easiest possible solutiuon, look at Erik's below, but it is less flexible if you want to add more types.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was also able to extend it, to include more trees in the pattern.

Answer (score 6):

If you data is as organised as you say, creating the "tree column" with following expression for the field calculator should work:

```
CASE
WHEN $id%3=0 THEN 'Cashew'
WHEN $id%3=1 THEN 'Baobab'
ELSE 'Banana'
END
```

Short explanation: This checks whether the feature's ID is divisible by 3, and if not, what rest (`%` is the modulo-operator) is left, then assigns the fitting tree-type. As ID starts with `0`, Cashew is assigned to all IDs with no rest.

Comment: I think you mistyped the second condition, it does not require `CASE`

Comment: @Taras I knew there was something fishy, thanks for pointing it out.